# How to add comments into a Xaml file in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, comments

I used this syntax as I found online but it throws an error:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
<!-- Cool comment -->
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

> 'Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C.
>   Line 4, position 5.' XML is not valid.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I assume those XAML namespace declarations are in the parent tag of your control? You can't put comments inside of another tag. Other than that, the syntax you're using is correct.

```
<UserControl xmlns="...">
    <!-- Here's a valid comment. Notice it's outside the <UserControl> tag's braces -->
    [..snip..]
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks so where can I put it? I need to put them in certain places that shows my additions to code.

Comment: As per my example, you'll need to put them adjacent to the tag whose contents you've changed. You won't be able to literally put them beside an attribute that you add inside a tag. Is this required for something that's going to automatically parse the XAML and do something based on your comments, or just for other people to see what you've changed?

Comment: You put them on the outside of XML tags. <sometag <!-- not here --> /> . If you go back to your code, you'll see that the place you put them receiving the error message is within a multi-line tag.

Comment: Although this answer suits me best, User500099 gave the exact answer to Joan's question.

Answer (score 38):

Found a nice solution by Laurent Bugnion, it can look something like this:

```
<UserControl xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:comment="Tag to add comments"
             mc:Ignorable="d comment" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="100"
                comment:Width="example comment on Width, will be ignored......">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here's the link:
http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2010/02/quick-tip-commenting-out-properties-in-xaml/

A commenter on the link provided extra characters for the ignore prefix in lieu of highlighting:

```
mc:Ignorable=”ØignoreØ”
```

Comment: Since XAML is a specialization XML (which is a specialization of SGML), you would think the `-- SGML comment --` style would work for inside tag comments.  But no, 99.44% of XAML parsers do not accept SGML in-tag comments.

Comment: This is the most useful answer!

Comment: I think the question by @Joan Venge is how to "Remove code temporarily" rather than "Adding information for human readers".

Answer (score 33):

You can't insert comments inside xml tags.

**Bad**

```xml
<Window xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
<!-- Cool comment -->
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
```

**Good**

```xml
<Window xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<!-- Cool comment -->
```

Comment: @kenny: That comment is OT and ranty...  Basing any programming language off XML sort of sucks, but at least XAML had the good sense to try to make everything as declarative as absolutely possible, which fits with the XML model.

Comment: @kenny a: xaml **isn't** a programming language - it is a markup language and/or serialization format, depending on how you look at it... and b: that limitation is not one of xaml - it is one of xml.

Comment: I understand XAML's limitation is that it's based off XML. So, XML is a second rate programming/markup language. Is that better?

Comment: >XML is a programming language
...what?

Comment: Someday, the world will stop referring to HTML/XML/et al as programming languages. Not today.

Answer (score 23):

*Just a tip:*

In Visual Studio to comment a text, you can highlight the text you want to comment, and then use **Ctrl + K** followed by **Ctrl + C**. To uncomment, you can use **Ctrl + K** followed by **Ctrl + U**.

Comment: Using this all the time when programming as usual but when I entered the XAML designer I didn't think of this one. Works fine.

Comment: this works only when you are outside of a tag definition. "<x><!--comment-->content</x>" works,  "<x <!--comment--> > content</x>" won't. I tried to comment out some properties on multi lines, it gave error.

Comment: Just for clarity, in Visual Studio 201 this refers to the `Edit.CommentSelection` and `Edit.UncommentSelection` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put comments inside UWP XAML tags. Your syntax is right.

TO DO:

```
<xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"/>
<!-- Cool comment -->
```

NOT TO DO:

```
<xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <!-- Cool comment -->
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone learning this stuff, comments are more important, so drawing on Xak Tacit's idea 
 (from User500099's [link](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2010/02/quick-tip-commenting-out-properties-in-xaml/)) for Single Property comments, add this to the top of the XAML code block:

```
<!--Comments Allowed With Markup Compatibility (mc) In XAML!
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ØignoreØ="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    mc:Ignorable="ØignoreØ"
    Usage in property:
ØignoreØ:AttributeToIgnore="Text Of AttributeToIgnore"-->
```

Then in the code block

```
<Application FooApp:Class="Foo.App"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ØignoreØ="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
mc:Ignorable="ØignoreØ"
...

AttributeNotToIgnore="TextNotToIgnore"
...

...
ØignoreØ:IgnoreThisAttribute="IgnoreThatText"
...   
>
</Application>
```